# Goertzel derivation

Tags: dft, algorithms

Referring to [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11579367/implementation-of-goertzel-algorithm-in-c), about Goertzel,I am confused about the final equation after N iterations
Where does

```
real = (q1 - q2 * cosine)
```

and

```
imag = (q2 * sine)
```

come from?

And how does the transposition theorem work? (i.e. swapping input and output stages for direct form II realization)

Answer (score 1):

They are needed in order to compute the complex-valued DFT output.

Desired realization

$
H_1(z) = \frac{1}{1-e^{-j\frac{2\pi k}{N}} z^{-1}}
$

The iteration computes

$
H_2(z) = \frac{1}{1-2 \cos(\frac{2\pi k}{N})z^{-1} + z^{-2}} = \frac{1}{1-e^{-j\frac{2\pi k}{N}} z^{-1}} \frac{1}{1-e^{j\frac{2\pi k}{N}} z^{-1}}
$

So that final step implements $1-e^{j\frac{2\pi k}{N}} z^{-1}$

because

$
H_1(z) = H_2(z)[1-e^{j\frac{2\pi k}{N}} z^{-1}]
$

Comment: Yes, But can someone derive the real and imag term?

Comment: @gari does referring you to Euler's formula representing the complex exponential as sum of sine and cosine help you?

Comment: That's fine. But why does the term q1 and q2 appear in real?